# How to prevent submenus of submenu from opening when clicking on first parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu and in a mobile view.

This is my Javascript:

```
$('#main-menu li').click(function(e)
{
    $(".mobile-menu-class").css("position", "absolute");
    var $el = $('ul',this); 
    $('#main-menu > li > ul').not($el).slideUp();
    $el.stop(true, true).slideToggle(400); 
});
$('#main-menu > li > ul > li').click(function(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();  
});
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<ul id="main-menu">
    <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="parent">
        <a href="#">Live Timing</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">MX World/European</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MX Austria</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SM Austria</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MX Slovenia</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent"> <a href="#">Motosross</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>
                <a class="parent" href="#">MX Austria</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">2016</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2015</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2007</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2006</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="parent" href="#">MX Slovenia Drzavno</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">2016</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2015</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2014</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2013</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="parent" href="#">MX Slovenia Pokalno</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu hidden-submenu">
                    <li><a href="#">2016</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2015</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2008</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="parent" href="#">MX Hrvatska</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">2016</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2015</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="parent" href="#">MX European / World</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">2016</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2015</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2014</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2013</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2012</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2011</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2006</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">
        <a href="#">Supermoto</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a class="parent" href="#">SM Austria</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">2016</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">
        <a href="#">Karting</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a class="parent" href="#">Kart Slovenia</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">2016</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2008</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2007</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2006</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">
        <a href="#">Cross-Country</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>
                <a class="parent" href="#">CC Slovenia</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">2016</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2015</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2012</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2011</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li class="search-btn"><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Everything is working fine, But when I click on a menu which has a submenu and which has a submenu that also has some more submenus, they get opened before I click on them.
How can fix this?

Comment: Please add your HTML to the question

Comment: use "Document.querySelector()"

Comment: Please any help anyone. It is very important and I can't solve this. I am not much expert in jquery